# In Honorverse canon known as of July 2014, which ships have been commanded by Honor Harrington?

Tags: honorverse

Across all the various stories of the Honorverse, the question does arise as to how many commands the now-Duchess has held.  Outside her serving in roles as a flag officer, which ships has she held personal command of over the course of the series to date?

Comment: As of July 2014, no ships at all. She won't be born for another thousand years or so.

Comment: Adjusted question to appropriately reflect that I'm referring to canon in print as of July 2014.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So far:

1. Light Attack Craft (LAC) HM LAC 113
2. Destroyer HMS Hawkwing
3. Cruiser HMS Fearless
4. Heavy Cruiser HMS Fearless
5. Battle Cruiser HMS Nike
6. Q-ship HMAMC Wayfarer
7. HMS Unconquered

Source: [Posts section of Honor Harrington page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor_Harrington#Posts)

Note that her position on Unconquered is an honorary position making her the only active duty admiral eligible to wear the white beret of a ships captain.

During the escape from Cerberus in [Echoes of Honor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echoes_of_Honor), Honor commanded the ENS Farnese (captured from the People's Republic of Haven). However, this was a temporary, jury-rigged, and unofficial situation that stemmed from a shortage of capable warship commanders. At the time, Honor was operating in her role as a full admiral of the Grayson Space Navy and would not normally have been eligible for starship command.

In [Ashes of Victory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashes_of_Victory), Honor was piloting the unarmed "civilian pleasure craft" *Jamie Candless*, which she owned. Compared to her official RMN commands, the *Jamie Candless* is barely even a ship, but technically, she was in command. It was this ship that she used to shield *Grayson One* from missiles fired by Massadan terrorists.

In the short story *Ms. Midshipwoman Harrington* (from [Changer of Worlds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changer_of_Worlds)), during the final battle, tactical command of the *War Maiden* fell to Honor due to the death, disablement, or loss of communications of all of the ship's senior officer..

Comment: Of interest, the HMS Unconquered command does appear to count towards the "hyper-capable command stars".  [The cover of A Rising Thunder](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-1eid8i0EoWU/UC-bv2htvvI/AAAAAAAAAgo/IaXQDSabJWA/s1600/A_Rising_Thunder.jpg) shows 6 such stars on her uniform.

Comment: Would the Elysian Space Navy ship she and Warner Caslet were on count as her own command in this case?  It doubled as her own ship as well as her convoy flag, it seemed.

Comment: Wasn't there a craft she commanded when they escaped captivity? (been a long while since I read HH so I don't recall if they used Havenite's craft for the escape or their own ship)

Comment: Also, I don't recall the technicalities but wasn't she effectively in command of War Maiden during the last fight in Ms. Midshipwoman Harrington?

Comment: @DVK Anything else? :-)

Comment: @Donald.McLean - not off the top of my head. But it's been years since I read the books so no guarantee it's exaustive.

Comment: @Donald.McLean - BTW, that's 2 different crafts in "
In Enemy Hands"- one the small craft they used to escape from *PNS Tepes* to Hades. And possibly another they used to escape FROM Hades if they were different - presumably *Farnesse* you mentioned. Excellent edits!

Comment: @DVK Actually, I'm just about positive that Honor was a passenger in the first case (being badly injured and malnourished) and did not leave the surface until after Farnese was captured in the second case.

Comment: There is something fishy in that topic in the series, because I was quite sure there were few descriptions of the decorations of her uniform and - lo and behold - *Field of Dishonor* says she has THREE stars on the uniform (scene of her duel with Summervale), which is clearly incorrect, as she is CO of **Nike** at this time, which was her FOURTH hyper-capable command (in terms of distinct ships, because two of those are bearing the same name, so there's that). This means, though, that **War Maiden** deifinitely doesn't qualify as a command.

Answer (score 0):

I think she was a Commodore by the time she was captured by the Peeps, so Nike would have been her last as "Mistress after God" though she had several flagships as Commodore and Admiral.

I don't think she was ever actually in command of a Grayson ship, since she started her service with them ("Flag in Exile") with Yu as her flag captain.

Joey

Comment: This doesn't seem to contain enough new information to be a standalone answer, especially since there is already an accepted answer. You may want to post this as a comment. And welcome to Sci-Fi and Fantasy SE!